# Do I need a transit visa for India to USA via Dubai?

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, uae

If I book a flight (Emirates) from New Delhi to Fort Lauderdale via Dubai, i.e halt at Dubai for a duration of 2 hours or 8 hours, then will there be any problem? Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: As long as you don't leave the transit area of the airport either layover is fine! See the linked duplicate for more details.